# MySQL Insert Trigger: Checking for duplicate entries before executing

Tags: mysql

I've got a trigger running "copying" entries from my Home Assistant (home automation software) database to another table in another DB. Home Assistant stores entries in a table called "states". If there's a new entry for the entity_id of my Nokia (Withings) wifi scale, I want to copy it's values over to my "health" table in DB "home". So far, so good, it is working using this trigger:

```
BEGIN
    IF new.entity_id = '[my_wifi_scale]'
        THEN INSERT INTO my_db.health (user, datetime, metric, val1, val2)
        VALUES ('[my_username]', new.last_changed, 'weight', new.state, JSON_EXTRACT(new.attributes, '$.fat_ratio'));
    END IF;
END
```

Now I would like to check if the new entry does already exist. Home Assistant is receiving the values regularly and doesn't care if the data is redundant.

How can I change the trigger so that it only inserts the value into my "health" table if fields "user", "val1" and "val2" are differing from the previous entry? I don't care if it checks the trigger's table (Home Assistant's "states") or my own ("health").

I did try adding constraints to my "health" table, but this does not comply with other values stored in it, like for example blood pressure values, which are more likely to repeat. Therefore I am looking for a change to the trigger.

Any ideas?

Thanks / regards.

Comment: `IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM health WHERE user=NEW.user AND val1=NEW.val1 AND val2=NEW.val2) = 0 THEN`